# How to fix the position of Button in Android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I am working on a project in which I need to dynamically add `TextView` and `Spinner` as well through the program. I was able to add these two things dynamically from my program successfull.

Below is the XML layout I have used for that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/llayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Save" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

Problem Statement:-
```

So what I want is- All the `TextView` and `Spinner` should get shown firstly then in the last `Button` should get shown.

But what is happening currently `Save Button` gets shown at the Top and then all the other `TextView and Spinner` gets shown.

How can I make sure, that Button comes at the bottom of screen.

Below is the screenshot from which you can figure out the problem. I want to show the Save button at the bottom of screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can create a button like this in the code and added to your layout after adding all the spinners and textviews like below, you will have to remove the declaration of the button from your xml:

```
   Button button = new Button(this) ///this is a context object

   button.setWidth(100);
   button.setText("Save");


  layout.addView(button);
```

You can dynamically create the layout and add the button to that layout and then add this layout to the Super layout

Or what you can do is Declare a new xml file in the res/layout/savebutton_layout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/lLayoutBT"

        >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/saveBT"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:text="@string/save" />


   </LinearLayout>
```

Now in your code you will have to find this layout containing the button and then add this layout to your main layout (just like you were adding your button)

For example

```
     LinearLayout buttonLayout =(LinearLayout)  view.findViewById(R.id.lLayoutBT);  
     views.add(buttonLayout);
```

Comment: I tried this, but in this case. Button is is really big just the width of the screen. I want Button to get shown exactly as it is getting show in my image in the question. Any thoughts how to make that work?

Comment: You need a layout. I have edited my answer and added the sample code to add the button to layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` then add this in your `Button`

```
<Button
...
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

it should give you what you want. I use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as often as possible anymore because in most instances, it is the more flexible and efficient. They take a little more time to get used to but are definitely worth taking the time to understand and implement

**Edit**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Something like that should work. You may have to play with it a little to get exactly what you want but that should get you there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you provide me the XML that I should use here in my code. As I believe I messed up something in my code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `RelativeLayout` (instead of a `LinearLayout`) you have access to properties like:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
...
</Button>
```